# Switching Windows 2003 Active Directory servers

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

Newb question:

I have two servers, call them OLD and NEW, on a domain that are apparently replicating Active Directory just fine.

The last time I had this setup it was to migrate from 2000 to 2003.  I had to do the whole "create BDC, promote, disconnect old PDC (now a BDC)" thing.

This time I'm just going from 2003 to 2003 on different hardware.  Now that they're replicating, do I just down the old server?

(Thanks for the help, it's hard to google things when you don't know the current and/or proper terminology to describe what you're trying to do.)

Comment: Might I gently suggest that you buy some books on the topic, posthaste. The fact that you're calling your servers PDC and BDC in 2010 is giving me goosebumps. To explicate : not since NT 4.0 domains have there been PDC and BDC, there are only DCs in Active Directory. There is a FSMO role called PDC emulator, but for day-to-day stuff, it's no more important than any other DC.

On-topic: If the old server is reliable, leave it there and just add the new server and DCpromo it. You generally want to have redundant DCs in a domain.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  We generally just run one server, it's a very small shop, and I thought (since we still have some older client hardware running Win98) that being in compatibility mode they were still called that when I did the migration in 2006.  Also, the old server is on its last legs...

Comment: @Kev: If you have the Windows Server license laying around I would keep the old computer running as a domain controller and doing nothing else. It's a very cheap "insurance policy". Disaster-recovery of AD w/ a single domain controller isn't much fun. Having a replica DC around makes life a lot easier if disaster strikes.

Comment: It's "cheap" except that it needs new parts--we just had a drive fail on it yesterday.  I wasn't kidding about last legs...  Also I don't have an extra license, just the original, so I technically shouldn't run both of them at the same time.

Comment: @mifinni, just a follow-up, I noticed the term 'PDC' in my event log this morning, and MS still uses the term in articles such as this one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042  (And the Applies To list has Win2003 as the oldest version...)

Comment: @kev: One domain controller in each domain holds the 'PDC Emulator' role, but that does not make its copy of Active Directory some kind of special 'primary' copy. Active Directory is multi-master, and each DC in a domain holds an equal copy of the directory (RoDC's nonwithstanding). Re: a second DC being 'cheap': Be sure you are getting good System State backups of your lone DC and can acquire a hardware-similar machine. In the event of failure, being able to restore that box from "bear metal" is your only option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you run dcpromo on the old DC and demote it, the dcpromo process will transfer the FSMO roles to the new DC. Make sure to update your clients to use only the new DC for DNS if the new DC will be the only remaining DC\DNS server.

Comment: Ah, so you *do* still have to demote, it's not like a multi-master mirror.  Thanks!  And I assume I'd update the clients by just changing DHCP settings...

Comment: Yes, running dcpromo to demote the old DC will remove it from AD and DNS and transfer the FSMO roles to the remaining server. Modifying your DHCP accordingly will take care of the clients.

Comment: Also, if you simply shut off the old DC then you'd have to manually remove it from AD and DNS, which is a pain. Dcpromo is the "graceful" way of removing a DC.

Comment: @Kev - you do not *have* to demote. AD domains are mult-master. More advice in my comment above.

Comment: @mfinni: The process of running dcpromo on the old DC will demote it back to being a member server, remove it from AD as a DC, remove it's SRV records from DNS, and transfer any FSMO roles it has to another DC. IMHO, dcpromo is the preferred method of removing a DC.

Comment: You actually should demote otherwise you'll still have an orphaned DC in your AD (single master vs multi master doesn't come into it).  You can of course just power it down and use NTDSUTIL to remove the orphaned DC, but that should not be used unless you have no other option (e.g. catastrophic hardware failure and no backup, or some idiot just powers it down).  Demote is the graceful way to go.

Comment: @joeqwerty - my advice is not to skip dcpromo and shut it off, my advice is actually to leave it powered on and as a DC. Like I said, more advice upthread.

Comment: @mfinni: I see what you're saying but it sounds like the OP wants to jettison the old server.